# Restructuring JSON with JavaScript by specific rules

Tags: javascript, json

I have a list of JSON objects in javascript looks like this:

```
[{"model":"alpha", "ports":4},
{"model":"beta", "ports":4},
{"model":"beta", "ports":1},
{"model":"beta", "ports":43},
{"model":"gamma", "ports":66},
{"model":"omega", "ports":6},
{"model":"omega", "ports":1}]
```

Now I need to figure out all the lines that have the same `model` value, then add a `include` key to the first item in which, finally make the value of the `include` key be a list of the rest "same model" lines.

Output should be like this:

```
[{"model":"alpha", "ports":4},
{"model":"beta", "ports":4, "include":[
{"model":"beta", "ports":1},
{"model":"beta", "ports":43}]},
{"model":"gamma", "ports":66},
{"model":"omega", "ports":6, "include":[
{"model":"omega", "ports":1}]}]
```

Anyone could give me a direction of how to achieve this?

Comment: Is the JSON ordered ? If so, you just need to read it and create the include values if the previous as the same model as the current one (in the loop)

Comment: @AxelH Yes, for now it is, but I can't guarantee it will always be ordered because it is not generated on my own but returned from an API instead. So I would like a robust solution.

Comment: lodash is an easy option for stuff like this. See e,g, https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy

Comment: just checked lodash out, it's really convenient! but third party libraries are limited in this project so a raw javascript solution is preferred here @georg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop and `thisArg` param

```js
var data = [{"model":"alpha", "ports":4},
{"model":"beta", "ports":4},
{"model":"beta", "ports":1},
{"model":"beta", "ports":43},
{"model":"gamma", "ports":66},
{"model":"omega", "ports":6},
{"model":"omega", "ports":1}];

var result = [];

data.forEach(function(e) {
  if(!this[e.model]) {
    this[e.model] = e;
    result.push(this[e.model]);
  } else {
    this[e.model].include = (this[e.model].include || []).concat(e);
  }
}, {});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: you pollute the window with the models,"this" in your forEach is window

Comment: @Vladu Ionut Forgot to add  object, fixed it.

Comment: such a elegant approach, didn't know javascript's `forEach` is so powerful. It works really well but I still need some time checking some references to understand this beautiful code block.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
var obj =[{"model":"alpha", "ports":4},
{"model":"beta", "ports":4},
{"model":"beta", "ports":1},
{"model":"beta", "ports":43},
{"model":"gamma", "ports":66},
{"model":"omega", "ports":6},
{"model":"omega", "ports":1}];

var res = obj.reduce(function(obj,currentValue){
  if (obj.length && obj[obj.length-1].model == currentValue.model){
  obj[obj.length-1].include=obj[obj.length-1].include || [];
  obj[obj.length-1].include.push(currentValue);
  }else{
    obj.push(currentValue)
  }
  return obj;
},[]);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function processData(data) {
  return data.reduce(function (result, item) {
    var first = result.find(function (i) {
      return i.model === item.model;
    });
    if (!first) {
      item.include = [];
      result.push(item);
    } else {
      first.include.push(item);
    }
    return result;
  }, []);
}

var data = [{"model":"alpha", "ports":4},
  {"model":"beta", "ports":4},
  {"model":"beta", "ports":1},
  {"model":"beta", "ports":43},
  {"model":"gamma", "ports":66},
  {"model":"omega", "ports":6},
  {"model":"omega", "ports":1}];

console.log(processData(data));
```

Comment: Well, not maybe the most beautiful part of software, but why to downvote if it's also one working approach..?

Comment: Yes man you certainly don't deserve this, I've up voted your answer but it will not change anything at this very moment because of my poor reputation. Sorry.